# Google sheets - script - Dating a cell with contents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a lot of cells with tasks to do. Once the task done, I want be able to put today's date at the beginning of the text with a button. Without creating another cell, and without overwriting the existing text.

I already know how to create a button, but i don't know if it's possible to modify the cell contents with the script.

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `var d=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM dd, yyyy");
sh.getRange('A1').setValue(d+ ' ' + sh.getRange('A1').getValue());`

Comment: Thank you Cooper ! I try your line and i come back to you :D

Comment: You could use a checkbox next to each cell instead of a button. This way you could keep track of which task gets edited with an `onEdit`. Otherwise you would need to have a function for each task, or make sure the correct cell (or row) is selected before clicking the button. Would that be a good workaround?

Comment: You guys are awesome ! lamblichus... You're crazy to spend so much time to answer me :O Are you a trainer ? Thank you, it works perfectly. I love your second method but it's technically impossible to apply in my case. But it motivates me for learning. Thank you, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method #1: Button:

If you want to trigger this using a single button and a single function, you need to find a way for the script to know which cell it has to edit. Otherwise, you would need to have a function for each different cell with tasks, and one button for each of those functions.

A way to track this is to use [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()), which will return the currently selected cell. If you want to follow this method, **you should make sure the cell you want to edit is selected when the button is clicked**.

```js
const addDate = () => {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); // Get currently selected cell
  const dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // Your desired date format. Change according to your preferences
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), dateFormat);
  cell.setValue(date.concat(' - ', cell.getValue())); // Append date to the selected cell
}
```

#### Method #2: Checkboxes and onEdit:

Another option would be to use checkboxes instead of a button. The idea would be to insert a checkbox for each cell with tasks. Then, you can use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to track changes to these checkbox, so that the corresponding task cell gets edited if the checkbox is marked. The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) would be used to get information on which cell is edited.

For example, if column A was your tasks, and column B the checkboxes, you could do this:

```js
const onEdit = e => {
  const range = e.range;
  const editedCol = range.getColumn(); // Edited column index
  const checkCol = 2; // Checkbox column (B, change accordingly)
  const taskCol = 1; // Tasks column (A, change accordingly)
  if (editedCol === checkCol && e.value === "TRUE") { // Check that checkbox is edited and marked (column B and TRUE)
    const editedRow = range.getRow(); // Edited row index
    const dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // Your desired date format. Change according to your preferences
    const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), dateFormat);
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const taskRange = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1);
    taskRange.setValue(date.concat(' - ', taskRange.getValue())); // Append date to corresponding cell
  }
}
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange())
- [Event objects: onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)